# Triangle and Vectors.

Tags: geometry, triangles, vectors

In triangle $\triangle ABC$, If $(\overrightarrow{AB}-3\overrightarrow{AC}) \perp \overrightarrow{CB}$, what is the largest value can angle $\angle BAC$ attain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using analytical geometry, you can assume without loss of generality $A=(0,0)$, $B=(1,0)$ and $C=(x,y)$. Expressing the perpendicularity condition will allow you to eliminate one of $x$ or $y$. Express the angle as a function of the remaining unknown.

Comment: Excellent solution !!